# WebStorm auto complete & auto import are not working

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, ide, webstorm, auto-import

I work on React-Native in WebStorm.

### Problem 1

I have some class, I want use auto import function of WebStorm, It works for some classes, but not for all.

#### When I type name and hit `Ctrl + Space`, it does not auto import class.

[image: No import suggestion]

#### I tried `Alt + Enter` also, it has no import suggestion in list.

[image: no imports]

### Problem 2

Then I manually imported the class, now WebStorm is not able to show methods suggestion with auto complete, when I press `Ctrl + Space`, my methods are not listed there.

[image: image3]

**Utility.js**

```
export function alertMessage(alertMessage) {
  Alert.alert(
    "Alert",
    alertMessage,
    [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }],
    { cancelable: false }
  );
}
```

Is there some setting of WebStorm I am missing. I want to improve my productivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting your function using [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Description) syntax (`export function alertMessage()`), but importing it as default, aliasing it to `Utility`; the IDE can't know what `Utility` is, thus no completion/autoimport is provided. Either change your export to default, or import your function using [named import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_single_export_from_a_module) syntax

Comment: There are several methods in Utility class, so what should I do, change to `default` ? I don't want all methods in suggestion, I want suggestion by class name, so the all methods does not show up all time.

Comment: haven't got what you mean, sorry. In the code you provided, I can only see a single function exported via named export. I can't see any classes with methods. If you like to export a single entity from your module, use default export; to export multiple things, use named exports.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to achieve correct code completion while developing any (not only react) app is to add support for required type scrip libraries via IDE itself. Assuming you using `Web Storm` IDE for development:

- Go to `Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) -> Languages & Frameworks`
- Expand JavaScript->Library
- When using react, I suggest to add: `react; react-dom; react-native` (for mobile app development)
- Click `Apply` when you done

Answer (score 2):

Just Install `@types/react-native` for suggestions, type hints and Auto imports.

Npm

> `npm install @types/react-native`

Yarn

> `yarn add @types/react-native`

Works like charm for me in Webstorm :) before its was not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with @tanstack/react-table. To resolve it, I added the @tanstack folder from node_modules.

**Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries then click Add**

This approach resolved the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pN0f.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxpIS.png)